# Should I be using loop cuts near edges to give my game models harder edges?

Tags: modeling

The title pretty much explains it all. I've been modeling various different things for a personal game I'm working on, and I'm trying to keep the poly count low. That lead me to wonder if the method of using loop cuts near edges to make them more defined is the best method for something like a game model.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't worked on game models, but this method does solves it for me. Another method is to probably increase the crease at the edges.

Comment: I wouldn't say that this is a good way. When the game model has to maintain low poly count this is something you want really not add as it can increase geometry a lot. This would be probably fixed by vector displacement map that can fake hard edged details even on a flat surface.